# Remove square brackets and parenthesis from values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
val_list = []
val_list_y = []
val_list_df = pd.DataFrame([])

for img in os.listdir(exa_test_dir):
    val_list.append(exa_test_dir +img)
    img_name = img.split('.')[0]
    val_list_y.append(val_df[val_df['filename_seconds']==img_name]['birds'].values)

val_list_df['image'] = val_list
val_list_df['label'] = val_list_y
```

I want to create a Dataframe which has 2 columns ['image','label']

'image'- directory for image (I get that using for loop)

'label'- name of the label

'image' is working fine for me but when extracting label I get it in the format ['....'] .  I want to get the labels in the format ....    not ['....']

How can I remove the [ and ' characters?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining the values before each append to remove the square (list) brackets:

```
val_list_y.append(' '.join(val_df[val_df['filename_seconds']==img_name]['birds'].astype(str).values))
```